# Strange property assignment syntax?

Tags: c#

What's the following syntax? It's not compiling but it's from an old codebase.

```
private static JsonSerializer JsonSerializer { get; } = new JsonSerializer()
```

The compiler complains that:

```
Error   1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.
```

Comment: What version was this old codebase?

Comment: Are you sure it was ever compiling? I don't think that was ever valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have mentioned is `Getter-only auto-properties`  and it's not part of C#, not yet !
It's part of new language features of C#. They've been implemented using Roslyn, .Net compiler platform.
Roslyn provides you with access to interior parts of C# and VB compiler. You have full access to compilation results and even you can manipulate C# itself.
There are dozens of other feature that you'll see in C# 6, such as Declaration expressions :

```
int.TryParse(s, out var x);
```

Exception filters :

```
catch(E e) if (e.Count > 5) { … }
```

To see the full list of new language featurs and their current status, check out [this entry](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation) in official Roslyn page on codeplex.

If you're intersted in the idea and want to dig in, I would recommend watching this [build conference video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-577). It can give you the big picture of the role of Roslyn in the furure of C#.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, it turns out to be the .NET compiler platform (Roslyn).